# Trigger list all completions behavior in a bash function

Tags: bash, macos, autocomplete

I have this following handy little script that searches for aliases and bash functions.  I'd like to extend it to bash autocomplete, i.e. find all the binaries on my PATH.

Come to think of it, the std autocomplete behavior would find the aliases and functions too.  But if there is *just* a PATH binary list, that's good for me too.

i.e. how do I trigger the list-all-completions behavior in a bash function?

```
(venv) me@backups$  I entered a tab here
Display all 3093 possibilities? (y or n)
!                                         libocijdbc12.dylib
./                                        libons.dylib
2to3                                      liboramysql12.dylib
2to3-                                     libpng-config
.....
```

#### this is the bash script I currently use.

```
_getfilter(){

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        r_getfilter='.+'
    else
        r_getfilter="$1"
    fi
}

findcommands(){
    #hardcoding for now
    #_getfilter $1
    r_getfilter='^p'

    printf "\nfunctions:\n"
    declare -F | cut -c12- | egrep "$r_getfilter"

    printf "\naliases:\n"
    alias | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | egrep "$r_getfilter"

    printf "\nautocomplete:\n"
    <what do I use here?> | egrep "$r_getfilter"
}
```

I would prefer not having to trawl individual directories in PATH for me-permissible executables.  If that's the only solution, I would probably not bother.

the current `findcommands` implementation works on Linux and Mac.  My priority is getting it to work on my Mac, Linux too is a nice-to-have.

Typing `complete` and `compgen`, which seem related, shows no output.  and `man` has nothing much to say for either.

Comment: Are you looking for `compgen -c`?

Comment: looks like it. piping it through `wc` shows that 3093 hits. what does it do?  update:  just found https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/compgen-linux-command/ that says *list all the Linux commands (including bash shell aliases and functions) you could run on the server / workstation*  write it up, I'll accept it.

Comment: It is the command that provides command completions. See `help compgen`

Comment: ok. got it.  will try to remember to `man` *and* `help` next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for compgen.

```
$ compgen -c
ffmpeg
la
ll
man
if
then
else
elif
fi
case
...
```